# R Add String To Values But Not Last One

Tags: r, data.table, paste

```
data=data.frame("v1" = as.character(c("ab", "cd", "qx", "ef", "hg", "ba", "ab", "cd")),
                "v2" = 1:8)
paste0(data$v1, "x")
[1] "abx" "cdx" "qxx" "efx" "hgx" "bax" "abx" "cdx"
WANT: "abx" "cdx" "qxx" "efx" "hgx" "bax" "abx" "cd"
```

I wish to add the letter x to the end of all values of 'v1' except the last one. I showed my trial and what it gives and then "WANT" which is what I want to get.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
c(paste0(head(data$v1, -1), "x"), tail(data$v1, 1))

[1] "abx" "cdx" "qxx" "efx" "hgx" "bax" "abx" "cd"
```

You need to import your data using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
paste0(data$v1[1:(length(data$v1) - 1)], "x")

[1] "abx" "cdx" "qxx" "efx" "hgx" "bax" "abx"
```

To include the last element, append it to the above function:

```
c(paste0(data$v1[1:(length(data$v1) - 1)], "x"), as.character(data$v1[length(data$v1)]))

[1] "abx" "cdx" "qxx" "efx" "hgx" "bax" "abx" "cd"
```

Comment: no that excludes the last element. i want to include all elements but the last one should not have 'x'

Comment: Before you edited your question, `WANT` excluded the last element `cd`. Please, note your edits. I have adjusted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want add it as a new column. Using `data.table` we can do :

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)[, v3 := v1]
data[-.N, v3 := paste0(v1, "x")]

data
#   v1 v2  v3
#1: ab  1 abx
#2: cd  2 cdx
#3: qx  3 qxx
#4: ef  4 efx
#5: hg  5 hgx
#6: ba  6 bax
#7: ab  7 abx
#8: cd  8  cd
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution with `ifelse`+`paste0`:

```
paste0(data$v1,ifelse(seq(nrow(data))!=nrow(data),"x",""))
```

which gives

```
[1] "abx" "cdx" "qxx" "efx" "hgx" "bax" "abx" "cd"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse` approach

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
   mutate(new = case_when(row_number() < n() ~str_c(v1, 'x'),
       TRUE ~ as.character(v1)))
#  v1 v2 new
#1 ab  1 abx
#2 cd  2 cdx
#3 qx  3 qxx
#4 ef  4 efx
#5 hg  5 hgx
#6 ba  6 bax
#7 ab  7 abx
#8 cd  8  cd
```